# XRD data conversion

Tags: python, pymatgen, genomics

does anyone know how to convert xrd data in .str format to .cif format?

```
from pymatgen.core import Structure
from pymatgen.io.cif import CifWriter
import os

# Define the directory containing your .str files and the directory where you want to save the .cif files
input_directory = 'file path'
output_directory = 'file path'

# Loop through each .str file and convert it to a .cif file
for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".str"):
        str_file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)
        structure = Structure.from_str(open(str_file_path).read(), fmt="str")
        cif_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, filename.replace(".str", ".cif"))
        CifWriter(structure).write_file(cif_file_path)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_34392\2071889891.py in <module>
     11     if filename.endswith(".str"):
     12         str_file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)
---> 13         structure = Structure.from_str(open(str_file_path).read(), fmt="str")
     14         cif_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, filename.replace(".str", ".cif"))
     15         CifWriter(structure).write_file(cif_file_path)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymatgen\core\structure.py in from_str(cls, input_string, fmt, primitive, sort, merge_tol, **kwargs)
   2803             struct = ResIO.structure_from_str(input_string, **kwargs)
   2804         else:
-> 2805             raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized format `{fmt}`!")
   2806 
   2807         if sort:

ValueError: Unrecognized format `str`!
```

Every other approach is given the same error.